# catkin / ROS: How-to specify include path correctly when using submodules

Tags: git-submodules, ros, include-path, catkin

I am building a project using ROS and thus, catkin_make to build my ROS nodes and libraries.

The problem I'm facing is: 
I am using a git submodule in one package (package A) (and thus, I have a hierarchical include folder structure) and I have difficulties referencing a header file within that submodule.

In order to build the package B, which is dependent on package A, I have added the INCLUDE_DIRS statement to the catkin_package command in package A:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS my-submodule/include
  ...
)
```

The content of that directory is:

```
my-submodule/my-header.h
```

(I have put the header files under a folder, named after the submodule, as many tutorials stated that within ROS you should use this convention).

The include statement in a file from package-B reads like this:

```
...
#include <my-submodule/my-header.h>
...
```

This works fine - package B is being built (as I am using one combined workspace to build this).

But: When I switch to the target system, where I **only install** package A, and then try to build package B (on that target system), it does not build because the include paths are not setup correctly.

The INSTALL statement for package A looks like this

```
install(DIRECTORY my-submodule/include
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

This is mainly, because the installed folder structure on the target system looks like this:

```
.../ros/include/my-package-A/include/my-submodule/my-header.h
```

So, the install process actually puts that submodule's include-path under the package-A-include path (which is a different path structure compared to when I build the packages directly in one combined workspace).

And the CFLAGS for compilation only set the include directory to the folder:

```
.../ros/include
```

And thus, breaking my include statement in my package-B file:

```
#include <my-submodule/my-header.h>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? 
I am sure there are more people than me, trying to reference header files from a submodule within a package.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file `my-submodule/include/my-submodule/my-header.h` inside your package A, then two small changes to your install() statement should fix this:

```
install(DIRECTORY my-submodule/include/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

First, add a slash to the path (`.../include/` instead of `.../include`), which causes the *contents* of the `include` folder to be installed instead of the `include` folder itself (Otherwise you'll end up with `../ros/install/include/include/my-submodule/my-header.h`)

Secondly, use `${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}` (which points to `.../ros/install/include/`) instead of `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}` (which points to `.../ros/install/my-package-A/include/`) as destination.

---

The alternative would be to fix catkin, as

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS my-submodule/include
  ...
)
```

should theoretically already export `my-submodule/include`, so you can pick it up in package B with

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED DEPENDS my-package-A)
catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS my-package-A
)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Unfortunately, for some reason this is explicitely not possible when using `catkin config --install`. See https://answers.ros.org/question/335846/install_dirs-not-working-as-expected-when-using-install/.